# File Monitor in C# or VbNet

Tags: .net, file-monitoring

With dotnet is there a way to handle the file system activity? I need to do a software that capture file access (like Process Monitor by Sysinternals). I can not use FileSystemWatcher, because in case of network share it log events olso by other user. I need to log only the activity of current system. 
Someone has a solution or knows how it works Sysinternals Process Monitor?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/etw/event-tracing-portal

Comment: @SLaks Thank you for this resource